# AngularJS $q.all timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I'm using AngularJS's $q function to group together several promises. However, I also want to set a timeout to cancel this promise and do something else if there isn't any response for any of these promises after a certain time. Is this possible?

Code:

```
var data = {};
var map_dataFile = $http.get("GET Request 1"),
    node_dataFile = $http.get("GET Request 2"),
    country_data = $http.get("GET Request 3"),
    shipment_data = $http.get("GET Request 4"),
    location_data = $http.get("GET Request 5");
$q.all([map_dataFile, node_dataFile, country_data, shipment_data, location_data]).then(function(results) {
    data.countries = results[0].data;
    data.nodes = results[1].data;
    data.countries_indicator = results[2].data;
    data.shipment_flows = results[3].data;
    data.location_data = results[4].data;
});
//do something else if it takes more than 10s, and cancel the $q.all promise
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http` and the `get` method can take a config object. One of the supporting parameters on this config object is `timeout`. [See documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

You can pass a timeout value to `http` config and if any of the operation would take more time the complete `$q` promise would get rejected.